# getting CS1503 when im trying to create a rest api from a tutorial

Tags: c#, api, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to communicate with my node js backend from my Xamarin forms app from a tutorial and getting the following error

> ```
> Severity Code    Description  Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Kula.MainPage' to 'Android.Content.Context'   Kula    C:\Users\1243g\Desktop\Kula\Kula\Kula\Kula\MainPage.xaml.cs 28  Active
> ```

The error is under `this` in Mainactivity

I was wondering what I am doing wrong because this is the first time I'm trying to create a rest API code below. I think I'm close. So any implementation on how to use the right variables and fix it would be extremely helpful

**Main**

```
using Kula.API;
using Refit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

 namespace Kula
{
// Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
// by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
[DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    // set variables 
    Entry RinputEmail;
    Entry RinputPassword;
    IMyAPI myAPI;
    APIRequestHelper apiRequestHelper;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myAPI = RestService.For<IMyAPI>("");
        apiRequestHelper = new APIRequestHelper(this , myAPI);

        RinputEmail = this.FindByName<Entry>("Remail");
        RinputPassword = this.FindByName<Entry>("Rpassword");

    }

    async private void GTLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //navigate to Login page
        await Navigation.PushAsync (new Login());
    }

    async private void registerUser_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     await apiRequestHelper.RequestRegisterUserAsync((RinputEmail.Text).ToString(),   (RinputPassword.Text).ToString());

    }

 }

}
```

**API request helper** (one for login one for register)

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace Kula.API
 {
  public class APIRequestHelper
 {
    Context context;
    IMyAPI myAPI;

    public APIRequestHelper(Context context, IMyAPI myAPI)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.myAPI = myAPI;      
    }
    public async Task RequestRegisterUserAsync(string email, string password) 
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "no email detected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "no password detected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        //create params for request 
        Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        data.Add("email", email);
        data.Add("password", password);

        string result = await myAPI.RegisterUser(data);
    }
    public async Task RequestLoginUserAsync(string email, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "no email detected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "no password detected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        //create params for request 
        Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        data.Add("email", email);
        data.Add("password", password);

        string result = await myAPI.LoginUser(data);
    }
 }
 }
```

**MyAPI**

```
using Refit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Kula.API
{

public interface IMyAPI
{
    [Post("/register")]
    Task<string> RegisterUser([Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)] Dictionary<string, object>  data);

    [Post("/login")]
    Task<string> LoginUser([Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)] Dictionary<string, object> data);
}    
}
```

Comment: and... on which line does this happen

Comment: @TheGeneral sorry I should've been more specific. it is in "public MainPage()" on line "apiRequestHelper = new APIRequestHelper(this , myAPI);" when I initialize  APIRequestHelper values. the youtuber said I should try to use "Context" instead of "this" and in still did not work. if that helps at all

Comment: I think you are passing your page in, where it expects that application/forms context

Comment: @TheGeneral how would I pass through the applications context instead of page because in the video he just but "this". or do I need to implement a new api?

Comment: @TheGeneral I don't know if im doing something way wrong or just a little wrong when making a rest api. any info or implementations would be awesome

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin

Comment: how would I apply that to my api? @Jason thanks for the response

Comment: @Jason or do I need to make a whole new api with refit

Comment: @Jason to be more specific im using a node js backend which will authenticate users with firebase so I need to send a user (email,passowrd) get it authenticated and return the success or failure

Comment: use that plugin to get the `context` which `APIHelper` requires

Comment: @Jason im not sure how to implement it in

Comment: Did you read the docs?  What specific part are you having trouble with?  It appears that the only reason you need `context` is for the `Toast` calls, so if you get rid of those you shouldn't need context at all.  You should also be able to make the Refit calls directly from Forms without needing Android specific code.